# Active class on horizontal scroll - Angular

Tags: angular, scroll

I built a table with an horizontal scroll, the first column is fixed and it has a shadow.
I want the shadow to be visible only when the user scrolls horizontally.

For the shadow I created a css class called ‘active-scroll-shadow’

Is there a way to active a class on horizontal scroll event?

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-jqcb74?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this Helps:

On Element Scroll, get its **scrollLeft** value & update conditionally

Here's [a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-v5wh1d?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)!

Comment: Thank! that was exactly what I needed! One more question, I would like to add the shadow to the sticky thead too, It would be the same logic?

Comment: Yep,  It should work